# Kotlin Google MLKIT Face Detection , Face Circular Motion Enrollment

Tags: android, kotlin, face-detection, google-mlkit, face-id

I was building a face enrollment feature using google's mlkit, I am trying to capture circular motion enrollment like that of ios as shown below

[image]

I was able to achieve everything but i am only stuck in the circular motion part,

what I have used is the following

```
    private fun Direction(): Boolean {
        if (angley in 20f..25f && anglez in 2.0f..6.0f) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

Angle Y is given from MLKIT face.headEulerAngleY and Angle Z is given from MLKIT face.headEulerAngleZ respectively

but seems like the circular motion is kindly stuck for some angles, i manage to work out for left and some right but its not smooth such as for ios face id, bit of help on what i am missing.

Comment: Have you achieved this?

Comment: yes I did achieve this in mlkit but partially

Comment: Thanks for the info. Please reply if this is still an issue for you. We will note it down & hopefully improve it in future release.

Comment: Its no longer an issue for me